# R as.data.frame.matrix turns first column into row names

Tags: r

I want to turn a table into a data frame. Three columns should be there: 1. the zip code 2 outcome "0" and 3 outcome "1". But as.data.frame.matrix turns the zip-code into row names and makes them unusable.

I tried to add a fourth column with imaginary ID's (1:100) so R makes them to row names but R tells me, that "all arguments must be the same length" - which they are!

```
id <- 1:5000
zip <- sample(100:200, 5000, replace = TRUE)
outcome <- rbinom(5000, 1, 0.23)
df <- data.frame(id, outcome, zip)

abs <- table(df$zip, df$outcome)
abs <- as.data.frame.matrix(abs)
```

Some has a nice and slick idea? Thanks in advance!

Edit:

When:

```
abs <- as.matrix(as.data.frame(abs))
```

I get something close to what I want but the outcomes are together in one column. How to untie them, to make them look like the table again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get to your desired result easier with `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

id <- 1:5000
zip <- sample(100:200, 5000, replace = TRUE)
outcome <- rbinom(5000, 1, 0.23)
df <- data.frame(id, outcome, zip)

df <- df %>% group_by(zip, outcome) %>% 
  summarise(freq = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  spread(outcome, freq)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are supplying only a 100 values to a data.frame that has 101 rows.

```
> nrow(abs)
[1] 101
```

so this would work

```
abs$new_col <- 1:101
```

I think you want this:

```
abs2 <- as.data.frame(abs) %>% select(2,3,1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but that puts the new column at the end and the zip-codes are still the row names.
With cbind I put the new id's infront of outcome "0" but couldn't change the zip-codes either.

Comment: The simplest way would be `abs$col3 <- rownames(abs)`. This should add it to the last position as well. You can always rearrange the columns to the order you want.