# How do I keep as.data.frame.matrix from using my first variable as row names?

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to create a table of my data so I can sort my values for "gymnasiegrov" according to frequency. I write the following code:

```
#creating table#
vettig_tabell_1<-table(fulldata$gymnasiegrov,fulldata$totstatus_tri)

#creating marigins#

vettig_tabell_1<-addmargins(vettig_tabell_1)
```

At this stage in the process, gymnasiegrov is stored as a separate variable. I then write:

```
vettig_tabell_1<-as.data.frame.matrix(vettig_tabell_1)
```

At this stage, the "gymnasiegrov" variable disappears and the values turn into row names. This is truly unacceptable since I will need that variable in later steps.

How can I keep this from happening?

Small excerpt of data:

```
structure(list(gymnasiegrov = c("Hotell- och Restaurang", NA, 
"specialutformat program", "komvux", NA, "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
"estetiska programmet", "komvux", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
NA), totstatus_tri = c("troligt avbrott", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "troligt avbrott", "troligt avbrott", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier"
)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Big excerpt of data:

```
structure(list(gymnasiegrov = c("Hotell- och Restaurang", NA, 
"specialutformat program", "komvux", NA, "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
"estetiska programmet", "komvux", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
NA, "specialutformat program", "estetiska programmet", "medieprogrammet/medieproduktion", 
"specialutformat program", "specialutformat program", "komvux", 
"estetiska programmet", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "specialutformat program", 
"friskoleprogram", "teknikprogrammet", "specialutformat program", 
"teknikprogrammet", "Handels- och administrationsprogrammet", 
"Hotell- och Restaurang", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", 
"samhälls- och ekonomiprogrammet", "specialutformat program", 
"komvux", "specialutformat program", "specialutformat program", 
"bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", "komvux", 
"Handels- och administrationsprogrammet", "teknikprogrammet", 
"teknikprogrammet", "friskoleprogram", "specialutformat program", 
"naturvetenskapliga programmet", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
"samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", 
"Hotell- och Restaurang", "specialutformat program", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "komvux", "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
"estetiska programmet", "estetiska programmet", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
"naturvetenskapliga programmet", "Handels- och administrationsprogrammet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
"bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "Handels- och administrationsprogrammet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "estetiska programmet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "teknikprogrammet", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", 
"naturvetenskapliga programmet", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
"teknikprogrammet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", 
"samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", 
"samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", 
"samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", 
"teknikprogrammet", "teknikprogrammet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
"naturvetenskapliga programmet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", 
"teknikprogrammet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
"teknikprogrammet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "estetiska programmet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "teknikprogrammet", 
"naturvetenskapliga programmet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), totstatus_tri = c("troligt avbrott", 
"tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott", 
"troligt avbrott", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"troligt avbrott", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"troligt avbrott", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott", "troligt avbrott", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "troligt avbrott", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", 
"troligt avbrott", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott", 
"tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"troligt avbrott", "troligt avbrott", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "troligt avbrott", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott", 
"pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", 
"tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "troligt avbrott", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"troligt avbrott", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"troligt avbrott", "troligt avbrott", "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"troligt avbrott", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -162L))
```

I am aware of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53192270/r-as-data-frame-matrix-turns-first-column-into-row-names), but I will need to generate many of these tables. I'm asking specifically if there's an option in the as.data.frame.matrix-function for stopping this unwanted behaviour.

Comment: not familiar with `as.data.frame.matrix-function`, but you can always add `vettig_tabell_1$gymnasiegrov <- row.names(vettig_tabell)`

Comment: (a) This will be easier to test and understand with a smaller example. Perhaps 10 rows would demonstrate the problem just as well as 162 rows? (b) I think you lose `gymnasiegrov` earlier than you think - as soon as you run `table` it is converted to (essentially) row names. (c) Would adding the row names as a column work for you? Final step `vettig_tabell_1$gymnasiegrov = row.names(vettig_tabell_1)`?

Comment: Why not just `data.frame(table(fulldata$gymnasiegrov, fulldata$totstatus_tri))`?

Comment: If I create a data frame via that method I think I need to use the spread()-function later, I'd like to avoid that if at all possible

Comment: If I use the vettig_tabell_1$gymnasiegrov <- row.names(vettig_tabell)-solution the program complains that the data has 1 more rows than the replacement, something with the marigin I think.

Comment: Added smaller excerpt of data